# Computing $-\frac{655}{8}$ modulo 35 efficiently in Magma (CAS)

Tags: magma-cas

Modexp$(-81.875,1,35);$ 
will not work.

So what I have to do is the following:

1. Modexp$(-81,1,35); = 24$
2. $875/1000; = 7/8$
3. Modexp$(24*7,1,35); = 28$
4. Modexp$(8,-1,35); = 22$
5. Modexp$(22*28,1,35); = 21 \equiv −81.875 \mod 35$

But there has to be a more efficient way of calculuting $-\frac{655}{8}$ mod $35$. Does anyone know how that might be?

EDIT: Read comments below for correction.

Comment: -81.875 $\equiv$ 21 mod 35.

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense mathematically.  In particular, $-81.875 = -81 - \frac{7}{8}$, yet you multiplied the remainders of $81$ and $7$ modulo $35$.  I won't even begin to get into the ways in which the other steps are complete rubbish.

Comment: Okay, I did it wrong, I get it. That's not my point though, my point is to calculate a RATIONAL number Mod a positive integer in magma. I just gave an example. Like for example maybe -8445/101 (mod 39)

Comment: Why am I getting a non integer result? 
(8,35) = 1 so there should be a unique inverse of 8 modulo 35. 
I am doing this calculation because I'm working in a finite field and I'm still new to using these CAS systems.

Comment: If it hasn't occurred to you by now, $-81.875$ is not an integer, and it's not a member of any finite field that I have ever heard of, so why would you expect modular arithmetic to be integer-valued in this way over the rationals?

Comment: -81.875 = $\frac{-655}{8}$ = -655 * $8^{-1}$ (mod 35). 
$8^{-1}$ has an inverse (mod 35) so $\frac{1}{8}$ is an integer modulo 35. 
Thus so is $\frac{-655}{8}$ (mod 35).  
In fact $8^{-1} = 22$. 
Then -81.875 $\equiv \frac{-665}{8} \equiv 10*22 \equiv 10$ mod 35.

Comment: Specifically I am computing multiples of a point on an Elliptic Curve over a finite field.

Comment: The definition of congruence modulo some integer $m$ is given by $$a \equiv b \pmod m \Leftrightarrow m \mid (a-b).$$  Does your computation satisfy this definition?

Comment: Yes, since $8^{-1}$ solves the equation $8x \equiv 1$ mod 35. 
Since x = 22 we see that 8*22 - 1 = 5*35.

Comment: My point is that you should not be using such notation, if you want your questions to be clearly understood.

Comment: -81.875 is the numerical answer of my slope that I had got when attempting to find 2P for P on an elliptic curve E over a finite field of order 35. I am simply trying to find a quick and easy way to find what this number is modulo 35. I can obviously do this using several lines but it would be nice if I could do it in 1 or 2 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magma can be quite picky about where your objects live.  Though in this case, I can hardly blame it---why would you enter this number as the decimal $-81.875$, which will be treated as an element of a precision field, rather than the exact $-655/8$?  Here's what I typed into Magma:

> R := Integers(35);
>
> R;
>
> > Residue class ring of integers modulo 35
>
> R!-655/8;
>
> > 10

The ! is used to coerce $-655/8$ into the ring $R$.

Answer (score 1):

In *Mathematica*, the particular type of computation you are looking for is done with the syntax `PolynomialMod[-655/8, 35]`.  In Magma, I don't know, because I don't use it.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. It outputs 10 which is the correct answer.

Comment: This works for my homework but for my Final Exam I am expected to use Magma so I'm trying to get used to do computations in it. Still very useful because I'd always use PowerMod in Mathematica but this looks very helpful.

Comment: I am going to take a total guess (since I don't know Magma syntax) based on what you wrote in your question, and say that the command `Modexp(Modexp(-655,1,35)*Modexp(8,-1,35),1,35)` should work.

Comment: Hmm.. yeah that works nicely. 
I guess I will just use this same outline for now until I find a function in Magma similar to PolynomialMod for Mathematica.